# How can I setDraggable(false) on layer by name

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, kineticjs

I have a problem in my program. I want to setDraggable of layer to false. But I have no idea how to set it. I created the layer when user clicks the button. And the layer has a different name. The name of layer set to "abc"+i. i is a variable that always increment.
I'm using jquery-1.8.3.js, jquery-ui.js, and kinetic-v4.3.2-beta.js.

```
document.getElementById('computer').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    draw(images);
    layer.add(Img);
    stage.add(layer);
    i++;
}, false);
```

and here is the code of function draw

```
function draw( images ) {
    Img = new Kinetic.Rect({
       x: 50,
       y: 150,
       width: 50,
       height: 50,
       fillPatternImage: images.abc,
       name: "abc"+i,
       draggable: true
    });
}
```

then when user double click on that layer, a dialog box appear. And I saved the name of that layer to variable name.

```
layer.on( 'dblclick', function(evt) {
    var shape = evt.shape;
    name = shape.getName();

    $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog( "open" );
});

$( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    height: 350,
    width: 350,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
        "Submit": function() {
            **name.setDraggable(false);**
        },
        Cancel: function() {
            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }
    },
    close: function() {
        allFields.val( "" ).removeClass( "ui-state-error" );
    }
});
```

I don't know how to use that..Please help.. THx..

Comment: why not just use the shape variable? shape.setDraggable(false);  Since getName gets the name of the node, then you can just reference the node as shape right?

Comment: Also, you might want to look this up in the KineticJS API, but I think you can do stage.get(name).setDraggable(false);

Comment: i've tried shape.setDraggable(false); and it can. but when I used stage.get(name).setDraggable(false); in $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog it does not work.

Comment: I want the setDraggable(false) used when user press the submit button..

Answer (score 0):

```
stage.get(name).setDraggable(false);
```